# FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/simplelogin:32 failed: permission_denied

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Before in my app I was creating accounts successfully until I put some rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user 
       // account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in 
       // with an email and password
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.provider === 'password'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then, the accounts are created because I see those accounts in the dashboard. But once I try to create, I am getting this kind of errors

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/simplelogin:32 failed: permission_denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the user to be able to *create* their own node initially, you'll need to explicitly allow the case where the location is new.

Based on the [documentation on the `auth` parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/rule/auth.html):

```
".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid""
```

*Note: I'm not entirely sure this will work, but felt it'd be more readable as in answer-format than as a "try this" comment.*

Comment: Just add this rule and is creating the users with no errors in between, I am about to do another question regarding firebase. Thank you

Comment: Alternately, one could authenticate before creating the user record, which would work with the OP's security rules as provided. The profile doesn't necessarily need to exist to authenticate.

Comment: Aha! I was wondering why the security balked, but you're right: not being logged on (completely yet) would indeed cause `auth.uid` to be null. Makes sense now.